# Indentation inside a new environment

Tags: spacing, indentation, minipage

I want to have my text lines in a new environment indented from the left, as happens within

```
\begin{minipage}{...}
\end{minipage}
```

The reason not to use a `minipage` inside the environment definition is to enable page breaking within the environment. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best is to use the `adjustwidth` environment offered by the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage). It has the following format:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<leftmargin>}{<rightmargin>}
  ...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

The contents is indented from the left by `<leftmargin>` and from the right by `<rightmargin>`, as expected, and allows for page breaking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0em}
  \lipsum[3-6]
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

[image: Adjustwidth]

---

Here is a little bit of a hack: The standard `quotation` environment (which typesets it's contents as a list) offered by LaTeX might be of some help here. Using this as foundation, the following MWE provides the `shiftpar` environment. The optional argument specifies the left margin indent (default is `1.5em`, taken directly from the `quotation` environment definition):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{shiftpar}[1][1.5em]
  {\list{}{%\listparindent #1%
    \itemindent\parindent
    \leftmargin#1
%    \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \parsep\z@\@plus\p@}%
    \item\relax}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shiftpar}[3em]
  \lipsum[3-6]
\end{shiftpar}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

[image: Shifting a paragraph]

Comment: Thanks. Now is it possible to have the quotation environment give this, with no right indentation?

Comment: As you can see, I've commented out the `\rightmargin` adjustment from the `quotation` environment definition, thereby not setting it at all.